# Fully dynamic keywords using PHP

Tags: php, html

I had this idea for a completely dynamic keywords script that would allow me to simply write content for my website/when people post on my website and have the keywords generated automatically from the content that they have posted... I have explored this method below, but I'm not sure how to move forward. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
     $content = "everything inside the body of the page";
     $common = array(' a ', ' the ', ' I ');
     $replaced = str_replace($common, ' ', strip_tags($content));
     $array = str_word_count($replaced, 1);
     $count = array_count_values( $array );
?>
```

That code takes the content from the page, strips the HTML tags from it, creates an array from all of the content with each word having a value for how many times it is used in the page.

How would I be able to filter this array for words that are used more than X number of times?

EDIT: Thanks to Jan for providing their solution, very helpful for what I needed to do, ended up changing it slightly though (don't hate me too much, but I consolidated it into one line to save space).

```
if ( isset($page['content']) and $page['content'] != ' ' ) {
    foreach ( array_count_values(str_word_count(str_replace(array('nbsp', ' nbsp ', ' something ', ' that ', ' does ', 'that', ' that ', ' have ',' with', ' this ', ' from ', ' they ', ' will ', ' would ', ' there ', ' their ', ' what ', ' about ', ' which ', ' when ', ' make ', ' like ', ' time ', ' just ', ' know ', ' take ', ' person ', ' into ', ' year ', ' your ', ' good ', ' some ', ' could ', ' them ', ' other ', ' than ', ' then ', ' look ', ' only ', ' come ', ' over ', ' think ', ' also ', ' back ', ' after ', ' work ', ' first ', ' well ', ' even ', ' want ', ' because ', ' these ', ' give ', ' most '), ' ', strip_tags($page['content'])), 1)) as $keyword => $frequency ) {
        if ( $frequency >= '3' and strlen($keyword) >= '4' and strlen($keyword) <= '10' and strpos($keywords, $keyword) === false ) {
            $keywords .= strtolower($keyword).', ';
        }
    }
    echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'.trim($keywords, ", ").'"/>';
}
```

Comment: How would I be able to filter this array for words that are used more than X number of times? - Please explain. Give us an idea of what output you are expecting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can iterate over the array and test the value of each key and if it is high enough, then add the key to a new array as value.

```
$min_count = 1; // Number of times the word should be found inside the content to be considered as a keyword
$keywords = array();
foreach ( $count as $keyword => $value ) {
    if ( $value >= $min_count ) {
        $keywords[] = $keyword;
    }
}
```

`$keywords` now holds the words that are interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks! This was very useful... i updated my question with the solution I used.

Answer (score 0):

Consider filtering by adding the word to a new array. Each time you want to add a word form the old to the new array, check if the word already exists in the new array and use an if statement to prevent it from adding if it already exists

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
 arsort($count);
```

And take as much keys with maximum counts as you want